# Identify GLM-Poisson, GLM-binomial, LM-normal, or GLM-normal only by looking to data

Tags: distributions, generalized-linear-model

Is it possible to recognize if a dataset fits GLM-Poisson, GLM-binomial, LM-normal, or GLM-normal only by looking at dataset? For example, consider the following datasets:

- [NMES 1988](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/AER/versions/1.2-5/topics/NMES1988) (Demand for Medical Care)
- [Olympic TV](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/AER/versions/1.2-5/topics/OlympicTV),
- [Orange County](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/AER/versions/1.2-5/topics/OrangeCounty),
- [PhDPublications](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/AER/versions/1.2-5/topics/PhDPublications),
- [PSID1976](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/AER/versions/1.2-5/topics/PSID1976) (Labour Force Participation Data),
- [Ship Accidents](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/AER/versions/1.2-5/topics/ShipAccidents),
- [Swiss Labor](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/AER/versions/1.2-5/topics/SwissLabor),
- [Affairs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/AER/versions/1.2-5/topics/Affairs),
- [US Traffic Fatalities](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/AER/versions/1.2-5/topics/Fatalities)

Can we say they fit a GLM-Poisson since they have discrete predictors?

Comment: You are aware that we are talking in here about *conditional* distributions, so at best you'd need to have the ability to look at the data in multiple dimensions at the same time..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several issues here.

1. Note that what you call "LM-normal" and "GLM-normal" are the same thing.  You may be confusing statistical concepts with the R codes that are used to instantiate them.
2. The distributions / types of *predictors* is irrelevant.  We are generally interested in the response distribution.
3. Critically, however, we are interested in the *conditional* response distribution, not the marginal distribution (see: [What if residuals are normally distributed, but y is not?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/33320/7290))

The last point means it is often difficult to identify the correct distribution just by looking at the variable in isolation (e.g., in a histogram).

Typically, we identify a distribution / appropriate model by first thinking about the nature of our response data?  Are they continuous?  (If so, they *could* be normal, but they cannot be binomial or Poisson.)  If they are counts, are they out of a known total (like the number of heads from a number of coin flips)?  If so, they would be binomial.  If there is no upper limit, they *could* be Poisson (but actual Poisson data are rare).

Comment: Thank you. By looking at the dataset, I meant what you explained in the last paragraph. It answered my question.